# How to find the range where the given number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to check what range/level the number is in. I have the table of buy and pay. Only I can thinking of is about between. But here, it is different because the column is not only min and max.

`pay_level`

```
| id | type | buy1 | pay1 | buy2 | pay2 | buy3 | pay3 |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1  |  p1  |  10  | 100  |  20  |  80  |  30  |  70  |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 2  |  p2  |  10  | 100  |  20  |  80  |  30  |  70  |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 3  |  p3  |  5   | 500  |  10  | 400  |  30  | 300  |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

Ok, according to the table above. My goal is to see how much cost is the incoming order.

For example.

- A order p1 for 12 unit. So the price per unit is 100. Because he is buying between `buy1` and `buy2`
- B order p1 for 15 units. Then he got 100 per unit as well as A.
- C order p1 for 25 units. He got 70 because it's in between `pay2` and `pay3`.

What I can thinking of is to compare 2 columns where the order in between. So my code is:

`select * from pay_level where order between buy1 and buy2 and type='p1'`

But the problem is occurs when the order is more than 20 (of `buy2`). I know my English is not good to explain this clear enough. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First normalise your schema design...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wilf;

CREATE TABLE wilf
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,type INT NOT NULL
,x INT NOT NULL
,buy INT NOT NULL
,pay INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO wilf VALUES
(1,1,1,10,100),
(2,2,1,10,100),
(3,3,1, 5,500),
(4,1,2,20, 80),
(5,2,2,20, 80),
(6,3,2,10,400),
(7,1,3,30, 70),
(8,2,3,30, 70),
(9,3,3,30,300);
```

...and then your queries become trivial...

```
SELECT pay FROM wilf WHERE type = 1 AND buy < 12 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
+-----+
| pay |
+-----+
| 100 |
+-----+
```

(And C should have got 80)

Comment: This is also interesting. I'll see if I can redesign all related tables. Thanks.

Comment: Just let you know that I stuck with my old structure. And now migrated into your suggestions. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a CASE expression to navigate this one since you can't dynamically refer to a database object (table, column, etc) in your sql.

I think something like the following would get you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN order BETWEEN buy1 and buy2 THEN pay1
      WHEN order BETWEEN buy2 and buy3 THEN pay2
      WHEN order > buy3 THEN pay3 END as cost
FROM pay_level
WHERE type = 'p1'
```

Comment: This is a new world of mysql of me. I'll have a test on it. Thank you.